# Wait until file exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I've written a set of web services using Web Api 2. They eventually end up calling a CMD program that fires up a OpenEdge Progress client, passes a formatted XML string and then inserts records into a OpenEdge Progress database by calling a .p procedure (WebSpeed is not an option).

The .P file has a set of business logic to run against a Progress application. It subsequently generates an XML file on completion containing an < Error > node. If this node is empty - then it worked. If the file doesn't exist or the node contains text... it failed. I then read this XML file and pass the contents of the < Error > node back to the client in Web Api.

At the moment, there is a static delay of 10 seconds from calling the CMD/Progress applet, to attempting to read the XML file, to give the server time to run the .P file and create said XML file. This isn't great, though, and occasionally an error is returned to the client because it can't find the file, yet, the file was created 1 second after the response was returned because of abnormally high server loads. Alternatively, people are forced to wait 10 seconds when the response could have been handled in 2 seconds.

I need to come up with a way to "check until file exists" until a timeout period has elapsed. I've done some research and can't find anything suitable for a Web Api environment. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Code below - forgive me. I've very much been learning as I've been going along and am very new to this!

Controller

```
// the request date/time
DateTime requestDate = DateTime.Now;
// list of validation errors
List<string> ohValidation = new List<string>();
```

...

```
WebExtensions.callInsertProgram(xml, "JOBLOG");
ohValidation =     XmlExtensions.ReadProgressXmlFileWithArray(job.logjob.placeref, requestDate, "joblogging");
```

CallInsertProgram

```
   public static void callInsertProgram(string xml, string program)
    {

        try
        {
            using (Process p = new Process())
            {
                p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Rubixx\runProgress.exe";
                p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Rubixx";
                // stop windows from appearing on the server
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                // set the arguments for running. The program name and xml are passed in as arguments
                // wrapped in escaping "\" to stop spaces from being treated as a separator
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + program + "," + xml + "\"";
                p.Start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new OpenHousingException(e.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
```

ReadProgressXMLWithArray

```
public static List<string> ReadProgressXmlFileWithArray(string reference, DateTime requestDateTime, string folder)
    {
        // new empty list
        List<string> output 
            = new List<string>();

        // wait X seconds before doing anything 
        // to ensure the XML file has time to be created
        Delay_Start(fileDelay);

        // 
        string filename = fullFileName(jobno, folder, requestDateTime);
        string filepath = getFullFilepath(filename, folder);
        if (checkXmlFileExists(filepath))
        {
            // if so check for the existence of an error message
            output = getXmlErrorArray(filepath);
        }
        else
        {
            // if no file is found - the call to Progress hasn't executed. So tell the end user.
            throw new OpenHousingException("No OpenHousing file could be found");
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Delay_Start

```
    private static void Delay_Start(int Seconds)
    {
        DateTime StartTime;
        DateTime EndTime;

        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        EndTime = StartTime.AddSeconds(Seconds);

        do
        { StartTime = DateTime.Now; } while (StartTime < EndTime);
    }
```

FullFileName (needed because I can't be sure of XML filename until created. File Format is UniqueReference_DateTimeFileCreated.xml (xxxxxxxx_20160401-1100.xml) So, I have to wildcard search a folder with a unique reference).

```
    public static string fullFileName(string jobNo, string folder, DateTime createdDate)
    {
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        string folderPath = fileLocation + folder;
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles(jobNo + "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Where(f => f.CreationTimeUtc > createdDate || f.LastWriteTimeUtc > createdDate).ToArray() ;
        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            fileName = item.Name;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            throw new OpenHousingException("No OpenHousing file could be found");

        return fileName;
    }
```

GetFullFilePath (Can probably be consolidated into fullFileName)

```
    private static string getFullFilepath(string filename, string folder)
    {
        return fileLocation + folder + @"\" + filename;
    }
```

CheckXMLFileExists

```
    private static bool checkXmlFileExists(string filepath)
    {
        bool fileExists = false;

        if (File.Exists(filepath))
        {
            fileExists = true;
        }

        return fileExists;
    }
```

GetXMLErrorArray

```
    private static List<string> getXmlErrorArray(string filepath)
    {

        List<string> output
            = new List<string>();

        // read the text from XML file
        using (TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(filepath))
        {
            XmlSerializer xs
                = new XmlSerializer(typeof(JobError));

            // de-serialise the xml text
            // to a strongly typed object
            JobError result = (JobError)xs.Deserialize(txtReader);

            // if the xml file contains an error - return it to the client
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.ErrorText))
                output.Add(result.ErrorText);

            //check for SoR errors that are created under a different node
            if (result.LineError != null)
            {
                List<LineError> lineErrs = result.LineError.ToList();

                foreach (LineError le in lineErrs)
                {
                    output.Add(le.SorCode + ":" + le.Error);
                }
            }
        }

        return output;

    }
```

Comment: Does the CMD program run synchronously or asynchronously? If it's synchronously then you can simply wait for that to finish then read the output file. If it's asynchronously, then the simplest approach is to just poll the file-system every 1 second to see if the file has been created yet: `while (!File.Exists("myfile.xml")) { Thread.Sleep(1000); }`

Comment: SignalR might help - https://www.asp.net/signalr or manual polling (HEAD request) in fixed intervals until the file is available

Comment: @Developer From his question I think he's ok with the client call synchronously waiting until the file is available - he just wants to ensure that's as quick and reliable as possible. **Adam**: Can you clarify this?

Comment: @RB. - In that case, he wouldn't have got this error in the first place. _At the moment, there is a static delay of 10 seconds from calling the CMD/Progress applet, to attempting to read the XML file_ -> I think reading XML file is a different call

Comment: @Developer I see what you mean - I read that as all happening within the context of a single call because of the line `I then read this XML file and pass the contents of the < Error > node back to the client in Web Api.` - **Adam**: You definitely need to clarify - is there 1 HTTP call here, or 2?!

Comment: Everything is running synchronously. I'll add my code to the question and there is only 1 HTTP call.

Comment: @RK - you were right :)

Comment: Added all my code - any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @AdamParker Have you tried the two suggestions I put in my very first comment? Use [p.WaitForExit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit(v=vs.110).aspx) to wait for the process to exit...

Answer (score 0):

OK - so I think I was overcomplicating the problem.

Instead of waiting for the file to exist, I added a line into my CallInsertProgram method as below (as suggested by RB...

```
public static void callInsertProgram(string xml, string program)
{

    try
    {
        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Rubixx\runProgress.exe";
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Rubixx";
            // stop windows from appearing on the server
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            // set the arguments for running. The program name and xml are passed in as arguments
            // wrapped in escaping "\" to stop spaces from being treated as a separator
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\"" + program + "," + xml + "\"";
            p.Start();

            // ADDED
            p.WaitForExit(60000);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new OpenHousingException(e.Message.ToString());
    }

}
```

This ensures that the Progress cmd applet is completed before moving onto the next line - at which point the XML will have been created (or not if it's failed). Initial testing is working well. Can anyone foresee any problems with this approach?

Comment: `throw new OpenHousingException(e.Message.ToString());` is a not great idea. you are loosing a lot of information, doing `throw new OpenHousingException("callInsertProgram failed", e);` will pass the entire exception in as a inner exception and will keep information like the stack trace intact.